# d3.queue is not giving an output

Tags: dc.js

This is the [page](https://www.covid19india.org/deepdive) I am trying to make it dynamic by enabling cross-filtering.
So the thing is they are having multiple API.

For the top first two: `TOTAL CASES` & `DAILY CASES` 
They are using this [API](https://api.covid19india.org/data.json) and the third one in the top is based on this [API](https://api.covid19india.org/states_daily.json).

The bottom three `AGE`, `GENDER`, and `NATIONALITY` are from this [API](https://api.covid19india.org/raw_data.json).

In all the API one thing is common that is a date but there are some API in which some data are missing for few dates like there is a gap( Not available for some of the dates).

So I thought of combining all the JSON API in terms of dates and then allow cross filter because I believe I can enable cross-filtering between them. Correct me If I am wrong.

Like If I click on gender female since it gives info about total cases where the patient was female so only confirmed cases from the Total cases will change not the recovered, deaths as data is not available. SO I guess I should combine the top 3 charts together and gender, age and nationality charts, together. Then Dc js would be able to handle nicely filtering between each segments (cases related to landmark, cases related to person info).

**Line 123:**

```
var log = console.log; 

var q = queue()
    .defer(d3.json, "https://api.covid19india.org/data.json")
      .defer(d3.json, "https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise/history");

    q.await(function(error, data1, data2) {
      log("==========>");
    log("data1:", error,data1);
    log("data2:", data2);
});
```

This is not working because I can't see `console.log()` output.

https://blockbuilder.org/ninjakx/8c48ab6481311aa0452046d66c4d8701

So my questions are:

1) Why d3.queue is not working?

2) Suggestion whether combining all the datas together and allowing a filltering is a good idea or not as there is limited data. Should I go for cross filtering between the same api charts. So in this case I will have 2 segments (cases related to landmark, cases related to person info)..
Using DC js I want to make it more interactive and display more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### d3.queue is obsolete

The answer to your first question is cut-and-dried: you don't need d3.queue, and it was [deprecated and removed](https://github.com/d3/d3/blob/master/CHANGES.md#changes-in-d3-50) in d3@5.

As of d3@5, D3's data loading APIs use ES6 Promises instead of asynchronous callbacks, so you can use `Promise.all([...])` instead of d3.queue. Apparently no way to make the new API emit errors when called in the old way, so it just fails silently. :-/

The new way to write your code is

```
Promise.all([
  d3.json("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json"),
  d3.json("https://api.rootnet.in/covid19-in/unofficial/covid19india.org/statewise/history")
]).then(([data1,data2]) => {
    log("==========>");
    log("data1:", data1);
    log("data2:", data2);
})
.catch(error => log('error', error))
```

I find this much easier to read and understand. A nice side effect is that if you neglect to do error handling (like most people), you'll automatically get a clear message in the log.

[Working fork of your block](https://blockbuilder.org/gordonwoodhull/707fbf6e387dd63158fab2652d740b6a).

#### Combining multiple data sets

Your second question is pretty open-ended, maybe it would be better to bring that to the [dc.js users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!forum/dc-js-user-group)?

In general, it's difficult to cross-filter more than one data set. You would have more than one chart group that redraws together, and you'd have to manually add handlers on some chart to initiate, clear filters, and redraw the other chart group.

I haven't seen too many dashboards that do this. You'd have to make it clear to users what is going on.

Comment: Even I was thinking the same. Even if I am able to connect them(diff datas) still it won't convey much information because a lot of data is missing. Due to this : they won't relate to each other.